# Sharing multiple images/photos through the FB share opengraph function

Tags: share-open-graph

Is it not possible to share multiple images through the Facebook share opengraph function?

The code snippet reads like this:-

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.likes',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
          object: {
            'og:url': xxx,
            'og:title': xxxxx,
            'og:description': xxxx,
            'og:image': img_arr
          }
        })
      }, function (response) {
     // callback function goes here… });
```

It is required for img_arr to be an image array. But the dialog box shows up blank saying that “Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can”. The images being shared on the facebook post is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook no longer allows the overrides. You must have the og metadata in the head.